# Consistent URL in WordPress with Custom Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having issues with consistent URL with my custom posts.
I have a page that displays all posts in a given category:

```
http://thedomain.com.au/tour_category/gbr/
```

When I click on a post in that category I get the URL:

```
http://thedomain.com.au/tours/reefsleep-under-the-stars/
```

I want the URL for the post to be:

```
http://thedomain.com.au/tour_category/gbr/reefsleep-under-the-stars/
```

I don't know how to achieve this. I have the following code in the functions.php if that helps:

```
// Our custom post type function
    function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'tours',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Tours' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Tour' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tours'),
            'hierarchical' => true 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function my_taxonomies_tours() {
      $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Tour Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Tour Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Tour Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Tour Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Tour Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tour Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Tour Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Tour Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Tour Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Tour Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Tour Categories' ),
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
      );
      register_taxonomy( 'tour_category', 'tours', $args );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_tours', 0 );
```

Comment: have you read the code you have posted and compared it to the url you are describing?

Comment: I have, but I do not understand it enough to make sense of it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though you want to change this part of your code

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tours'),
```

to

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tour_category/gbr'),
```

The slug is the initial part of the url after the domain

Comment: I have multiple categories. how do I make "gbr: dynamic i.e using a variable to display the correct tour name

Comment: @AkiraDawson, the question you have asked is answered, you should accept this answer and ask a new question with the new requirement, its completely different again!

Comment: @David I made the change and it has not fixed the issue. I can't mark that as answered. I will make a new question. Thank you

Comment: you need to re-save your permalinks in the settings, then it will work!